# Create table inside aspx file

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table

I want to create a button line up in the page. It should be like code below in html.

```html
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

however, currently I am using C# and aspx file. Here is my aspx interface code:

```aspx
<%@ Page Language="C#" Async="true" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Translator2.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"  Inherits="Translator2" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <html></html>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="English" ID="enlabel" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">English</asp:Label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">

                        <asp:TextBox  Height="79px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="452px"  runat="server" ID="English" CssClass="form-control" />

                    </div>      </div>  

 <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" Height="39px" Width="100px"  OnClick="Detect" Text="Detect" CssClass="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I am trying to put the html tag inside the asp content but there is error:

> "validation(html5) element html cant be nested within element `div`"

and if I put outside the asp content there`s also error:

> "validation(html5) content is not supported outside `script` or asp:content regions"

My question is, can we create the `<table>, <td>, <tr>`,etc in aspx file? Because it seems not supported html tag.

I am still new in asp and c#, please give me some insight!

Comment: what if you put your table tags without the html tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<html>` tag from code, you don't need it here.

And you can use Table class

```html
<asp:Table id="Table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            Row 0, Col 0
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            Row 1, Col 0
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

Comment: after I add this <asp:Table id="Table1" runat="server">, 
my asp button and div class can't be used. it says "element button is not a known element. This can occurs if theres a compilation error in website or the web.config file is missing. Do you have any idea?

Comment: May be you forgot to add tablerow or tablecell? Button's must be in tablecell element. And don't use div in table.